# Converting Facebook profile to page, not all "likes" were transferred nor all "friends" converted to fans

Tags: migration, facebook, profile

A friend of mine asked me to convert his profile into a Facebook page. So I have initiated the migration process.

And I have migrated the friends into Facebook page fans.

He has around 4500+ friends in his Facebook account. But in the migration tool, the number of friends were shown only 3250. And when I clicked on "Select All" and clicked the `Next` button, the page only got 680 *likes*. When I checked the migration tool again, it was showing "migrated" below the name of all friends!

Why only 680 likes were received, whereas we were expecting it to have 3000+ *likes* as we migrated all friends to page likes?

My another question is, do we have to create a secondary Facebook account and add that account as the page admin for this new page? I mean the page is displaying a small message that we have only 7 days to complete the migration of data from profile to page. So after that, will we still be able to login with his profile account credentials to access his page?

Please let me know if you need any further explanation regarding the issue.

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per question post. Your "another question" should be a separate question.

Comment: @AlE., both questions were regarding the same topic `after converting profile to a page`. That's why I asked it in the same thread. I mean both will be faced at the time of conversion. Thank you.

Comment: I understand, but consider that someone might know the answer to one question and not the other.